# Using Excel VBA Combo Box to Draw A Chart From Different Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

Okay so what I am trying to do is have a userform with a combobox that displays each sheet as an option. I got that down. I want to be able to select a sheet and draw a chart from certain ranges on said sheet on my userform. I hope that makes sense.... Here is what I have got so far. It works with the first combobox selection, but once I change sheets and try to draw a chart from a different worksheet I get an error, "Method 'Values' of object 'series' failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance =)

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
```

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "Select A Client" Then
MsgBox "You Must Select a Name to Continue.", , "ERROR:Select A Name"
ComboBox1.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim MyChart As Chart
Dim ChartData As Range
Dim chartIndex As Integer
Dim ChartName As String

chartIndex = ComboBox1.ListIndex

Select Case chartIndex
    Case 1
        Set ChartData = ActiveSheet.Range("L4:L103")
        ChartName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart

MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = ChartName
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartData
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("J4:J103")

Dim imageName As String
imageName = Application.DefaultFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "TempChart.gif"

MyChart.Export Filename:=imageName

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(imageName)

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim sht As Worksheet, txt As String
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name
Next sht

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The only time you are defining `ChartData` is if the `ComboBox` `ListIndex` is 1. Any other selection and the `ChartData` object will remain `Nothing`. Therefore when you try to set your chart values to `ChartData` you'll receive an error.

It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do with the `Ranges`. If you want to define the `Range` on whichever sheet is selected in the `ComboBox` then you're code would need to look like this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ComboBox1.Text)
```

And delete your `Select` block.

All of your code is referencing the `ActiveSheet` which is probably not what you want, so you would need to replace all references to that with this new variable `ws`.

Comment: Im still trying to work through this here so Ill give you a brief rundown on what I am trying to do